# how to show only the centre of the wide image that will change according to the screen size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div style="width: 2911px height: 300px">
    <img style="float:left" src="../img/header1.jpg">
    <img style="float:left" src="../img/header2.jpg">
    <img style="float:left" src="../img/header3.jpg">
</div>
```

these are three wide images summing up to 2911px. now for instance when the screen is 2000px wide I just want to show centre of the above 2911px and if its smaller i want it to be smaller and not worry about hidden right/left side of image. I cannot figure out how to do so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have create a demo for you with a possible solution, check:

http://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/ue49awaL/1/

Relevant CSS code:

```
div{
    width: 600px;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

img{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
```