# Cannot center a fluid image in a fluid Div

Tags: html, css, layout, fluid

I'm having an issue with horizontally centering a fluid image in a fluid div. From looking high and low, the solutions others have found are not working for me, either I'm trying to do something too hard (I doubt it) or I'm working with different medium.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="BackgroudDiv">
    <img src="images/NumberTwo.png" alt="" id="FSBG"/>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0px
}
#FSBG {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 1040px;
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 585px;
}
#BackgroudDiv {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1080px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    background-color: #BF2527;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

"Margin: auto" does nothing as the width of everything is variable. In the code as it is, the left edge of the image "NumberTwo" is centered on the page. I want the center of the image to be centered. It behaves just as it should scaling-wise, but not in the middle of the page!

Any help would be much appreciated, it's been driving me up the wall. Let me know if more information is needed.

H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to remove the `position: absolute;` in the `img`:

```
#FSBG {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 1040px;
    min-height: 585px;
}
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/3w5rqg3d/1/

Comment: Ah I had tried that but then the image didn't follow the scaling "rules" I had set, changing the BackgroudDiv to be 100% height instead of a set height makes everything work. thank you very much

Comment: One more thing, if you will: When the aspect ratio of the window changes to be too narrow, I would like the sides of the image to cut off, as opposed to just the right side (which is happening now), any addition to make that possible?

Comment: Take a look at [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/3w5rqg3d/3/) using some code from [this another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30770629/4908989).

Answer (score 1):

As you are using position absolute, you need to set the top, right and left to 0px; and then you can add margin-left and margin-right auto.

**Example** - https://jsfiddle.net/zvbn2fak/

```
top:0px;
left:0px;
right:0px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

Please note that this is not best practice using position absolute on an image when its not need. Please read the comment by lmgonzalves, below with a better fix.

Comment: lmgonzalves Solution working for me, but thank you for taking the time to answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), but be wary that flexbox is not supported on older browsers.

```
#backgroundDiv {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

And that's it. `justify-content` aligns the items inside in the flexbox along the direction of the flex. I'm not sure if it works on `position: absolute` items, but you can check it out.

**Note:** I've left vendor prefixes for the sake of brevity, but you'll likely have to add those to get the desired effect across browsers.

Comment: lmgonzalves Solution working for me, but thank you for taking the time to answer :)